# Should this be excel or excels?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, relative-clauses

> Mike is one of those rare individuals who excel in all aspects of his life.

Is it excel or excels?

Comment: Rare are the individuals who excel in all aspects of life, of whom Mike is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the antecedent of the relative pronoun *who*? That will determine whether the verb *excel* is singular or plural as well as the possessive pronoun and the noun *life*.

If you invert the partitive construction, you get a sentence that reads:

> Of those individuals who excel in all aspects of their lives, Mike is one.

Here, it's clear that the plural *individuals* is the antecedent of the relative pronoun *who* and both the possessive and *life* should agree.

The difficulty arises because one attempts to apply a grammar rule drilled into our heads by an army of English teachers, but in a situation where it doesn't belong.

> One of the artists who were to be awarded a prize in yesterday's ceremony *was* stuck at the airport.

While *artists* is the antecedent of the relative pronoun *who* and thus determines the number of the verb in the relative clause, only *one* of these artists was stuck at the airport, thus *one* is the subject of the independent clause. The pattern *one of [plural noun] = singular verb* has been so fixed in our minds that we see it everywhere. Using a singular verb in your example is thus a *hypercorrection*.

Answer (score 0):

"Excels" - if you're going to use `his life`, the verb needs to reference <s>Mike.</s>

If you want to use "excel", then it should be "their lives" to reference individuals.

**EDIT:**

As @FumbleFingers stated in the comments, "excels" references ***one of*** and not ***Mike***.

Comment: Agreed the verb should be in the singular form ***excels***. But *not* because it references ***Mike*** - it's because it references singular ***one** of those people*.

Comment: Hmm... I agree with you on that. However, in case of needing to be politically correct, if we take out _Mike_ from the sentence should _his_ be changed _his or her_? I understand this is no longer a question about grammar but style, but I'm genuinely interested to hear an opinion on the matter.

Answer (score -1):

It's ***excel***.

The problem here is *his*. The noun phrase is "those rare individuals who excel", so *excel* is plural. What do they excel in? *Their* life.

There could be a question (and probably already is) about whether *life* should be singular or plural. I favour the singular.

> Mike is one of those rare individuals who excel in all aspects of their life.

Comment: I don't agree that the subject noun phrase is unquestionably *those rare individuals who excel*. It could just as well be ***one of** those rare individuals who excel*. It's true that Google Books claims 4480 written instances of [*one of those people who **like***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+of+those+people+who+like%22), but that must be set against 2950 instances of singular [*one of those people who **likes***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22one+of+those+people+who+likes%22), which is certainly fine by me. It's about stylistic choice/emphasis, not grammar.

Comment: And in fact it *has* to be seen as singular in OP's exact context, given *all aspects of **his** life*. If it had been ***their life*** that could be interpreted either way, whereas ***their lives*** would only really work if we assume a plural subject.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I fail to see any essential difference between KarlG's answer and this one.

Comment: KarlG's answer wasn't there when I commented before. I think you're right that it says essentially the same as yours, so I disagree with *both* of them (as regards the specific claim that *only* plural is correct). My position remains that (1) - a ratio of 4480:2950 for written instances strongly implies *both are in common use*, so in practice both are "valid" from my perspective, and (2) I've made the "logical" case for singular by pointing out that the referent can reasonably be seen as ***one** [instance of some category]*.

Answer (score -2):

Excels.

If you shorten the sentence to its minimum you have "Mike excels in all aspects of his life."

Though I might use "excels at" rather than "excels in." I might also be wrong.